# Unenlisting Orchestration using BTDF

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-deployment, btdf

I am working on a requirement where in we need to keep 2 out of 20 orchestrations in Unenlisted state.
I am using BTDF for the deployment. Even if I keep state as **Unenlisted** in the binding file, at the end of the deployment BTDF will start the application, which would result in starting all the orchestrations.
Could anyone please help me in achieving the same.
Below is the snippet of my binding file:

```
<Service Name="ACE.Claims.HFC.Integration.Orchestrations.getStockInfo" State="Unenlisted" TrackingOption="ServiceStartEnd MessageSendReceive InboundMessageBody OutboundMessageBody OrchestrationEvents TrackPropertiesForIncomingMessages TrackPropertiesForOutgoingMessages" Description="">
          <Ports />
          <Roles />
          <Host Name="${Hosts.ClaimsHFCProcess}" NTGroupName="${Groups.BTSApplicationUsers}" Type="1" Trusted="${Hosts.IsTrusted}" />
</Service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way through which we can keep orchestration in unenlisted state

1. Using BTDF PortBindingsMaster.xml file set the State="Unenlisted" for the Orchestration which you want to be.
2. using the WMI script we can Unenlist the orchestration post the successful deployment using the BTDF.

BTDF

```
<Target Name="CustomDeployTarget">
         <Exec Command="my_command_to_execute" />
</Target>
```

Script

```
cscript.exe "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\SDK\Samples\Admin\WMI\Stop Orchestration\VBScript\StopOrch.vbs" "myNameSpaceName.OrchestrationName" "myAppName" Unenlist
```

Comment: Yes, first step is not possible, please ignore the first step, you can solve your issue with the second post

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with just configuration.

You should be able to achieve this with a combination of two options:

- **EnableAllReceiveLocationsOnDeploy** = false
- And a **CustomPostDeployTarget** script to Unenlist the two Orchestrations.

Then you can manually start the Receive Locations to begin processing.